# GNOME hotkey for both workspaces and launcher?

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, launcher, workspaces

In Ubuntu 20.10, the super key would open the "show all windows" workspace view, and also allow me to type an application name to launch (ie. "launcher" functionality).  Now in 21.04, it seems like the super key only opens *either* the launcher *or* the workspace view.

If the functionality is no longer combined like in previous versions, is there at least some way to have one keyboard shortcut for the launcher, and another one for the workspace view?  In Settings...Desktop...General it seems like you have to pick only one to assign to the super key.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your issue right. Also in Ubuntu 21.04, hitting and releasing the <kbd>Super</kbd> key should show you the Activities overview, i.e., the screen with the search prompt, your open windows if any, the dock to the left and the workspace switcher to the right. As soon as you type, search results are shown as application icons in the top half of the screen, and results from other active sources (e.g. "Settings", "Weather", ...) below that.

> Is there at least some way to have one keyboard shortcut for the launcher, and another one for the workspace view?

It is there by default:

- To open the Activities overview, hit <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>
- To open the Show Applications view, hit <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>